# Oracle SQL count colums and group by date

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Hi I have a table like this one

```
C_DATE     SOURCE
11/21/2012  A
11/22/2012  A
11/22/2012  A
11/22/2012  A
11/23/2012  A
11/23/2012  A
11/25/2012  A
11/26/2012  A
11/26/2012  B
11/26/2012  B
11/26/2012  B
11/21/2012  B
11/22/2012  B
11/22/2012  B
11/23/2012  B
11/23/2012  C
11/24/2012  C
11/24/2012  C
11/24/2012  C
11/24/2012  C
11/25/2012  C
```

How can I have the count by source and by date as follows:
`c_date` source a source b source c

```
11/21/2012 1 4 0 
11/22/2012 1 1 1 
11/23/2012 0 0 1
11/24/2012 and so on..
```

The closest I have got is something like

```
 select trunc(c_date)  XDATE,  
        (select count(**) from TABLE where source='A') A, 
        (select count(**) from TABLE where source='B') B, 
        (select count(*) from TABLE where source='C') C
 from TABLE
group by trunc(C_DATE) 
order by trunc(C_DATE) asc
```

but it repeats the total count for each row I cannot find how to relate the count colums with the date.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: What's your Oracle version?

Comment: Then consider using a pivot for this (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php).

Answer (score 1):

```
select trunc(c_date)  XDATE,  
       sum(case source when 'A' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_a,      
       sum(case source when 'B' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_b,
       sum(case source when 'C' then 1 else 0 end) cnt_c,
  from TABLE
 group by trunc(C_DATE) 
 order by trunc(C_DATE) asc
```

**update** as long as you use 11g, you can use modern pivot clause :)

```
select xdate, a, b, c
  from 
(select trunc(c_date) XDATE, source, count(*) 
   from tab 
  group by trunc(c_date), source )     
   pivot 
( count(*) for source in ('A' a, 'B' b, 'C' c) )
order by 1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d0269/16

Comment: excellent...!   just perfect.  And what if I want an additional column that is the total of the three sources?   thanks a lot

Comment: @rjavy that would be just `sum(1)` or `count(*)`